# How to change neovim command-line popup to horizontal, or change direction key's behaviour?

Tags: popup, neovim

In neovim, popup of command-mode complete is vertical, but using `left` `right` to selete.

Can I change popup to horizontal? or use `up` `down` to select? How?

---

- this is neovim popup

[image]

- this is what I want

[image]

- or using `up` `down` to select

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `:h 'wildoptions'`

For the desired behaviour type `:set wildoptions=` in neovim.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to use `<down>` and `<up>` mappings for `wildoptions=pum`
from https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9953

```
if &wildoptions =~# "pum"
  cnoremap <expr> <up> pumvisible() ? '<left>' : '<up>'
  cnoremap <expr> <down> pumvisible() ? '<right>' : '<down>'
endif
```